# Which data type should I choose for a sequence of sorted integers?

Tags: java, types

I have a a row of int numbers, e.g. 1 2 3 7 8 9. They are sorted.

I often need to insert numbers in this row, so that the row stays sorted, e.g. 4 => 1 2 3 4 7 8 9. Sometimes I have to read the row from the start to a number, that depends on the numbers in the row.

Which data type to choose best and how to insert the new number best?

Comment: Trivially, a List. Using Collections.sort as required. Or perhaps a SortedSet, even.

Comment: Do you know something about the maximum number of numbers?

Comment: You can use a `List<Integer>` and do a Collections.binarySearch() to find where to insert a value.  This is faster than resorting the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sequence does not have repetitions you can use a `SortedSet<Integer>`, say, a `TreeSet<Integer>`, so that every time you and an element the sequence will remain sorted.

If the sequence does have repetitions check out Guava's [sorted multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset).

Answer (score -1):

try ArrayList.  it is much easier to manipulate than a simple array.  if you need to only work with primitives, this can still be done with an array of ints.

```
ArrayList<Integer> foo = new ArrayList<integer>;
foo.add(2,4) //puts a 4 at index 2, shifting everything else down
```

Comment: That won't allow inserting elements in the right sorted order position.

Comment: True, for that reason, List may be a better choice.  You could still do it, it would just involve a few extra lines of code to find the right position

Comment: List also doesn't allow that, at least not optimally. A `SortedSet` is the silver bullet here.

Comment: What about just an array?  you could add the number to the end, then sort it.

Comment: Once again, it's suboptimal, unless the sort happened once and no more items were appended afterwards. However, since the items are already sorted you might as well just keep them that way from the beginning.